# metricbeat is not installed but kibana log showing error related to metricbeat - "[elastic_agent.metricbeat][error] Error watching for docker........"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I have configured only elasticsearch, kibana, fleet-server, elastic-agent and apm-server. **I have not configured metricbeat. And we don't want metricbeat** but inside kibana log ( Observability > Logs > Stream ), It is showing

```
[elastic_agent.metricbeat][error] Error watching for docker events: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

From a link (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/metricbeat-not-using-docker-but-getting-error-is-the-docker-daemon-running/226696) I have found that I have to comment these lines from metricbeat.yaml:

```
add_docker_metadata: ~ 
add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

I have not installed metricbeat, but still I have found a metricbeat.yml at `/var/lib/elastic-agent/data/elastic-agent-b79a5d/components/metricbeat.yml`
And inside that file I have commented **add_docker_metadata: ~  and add_kubernetes_metadata: ~**
But still, It is showing the same error.
please help me with any solution.

Note:

- We don't want metricbeat.
- when metricbeat is installed automatically, it is not
  installed as systemd, so `systemctl stop/restart metricbeat` is not
  working.
- `ls /var/lib/elastic-agent/data/elastic-agent-b79a5d/components | grep metricbeat` is showing

```
metricbeat
metricbeat.reference.yml
metricbeat.spec.yml
metricbeat.yml
```

Please let me know how to solve this error to show or how to stop metricbeat. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Elastic Agent runs Beats under the hood ([FAQ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/master/fleet-faq.html#do-i-need-to-setup-elastic-agent)). You can disable monitoring collection configuring your Elastic Agent like described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/elastic-agent-monitoring-configuration.html